# How to update object at specific index in array within React state?

Tags: reactjs, state, immutability, deep-copy

I'm building a calorie counting application using React.  One of my components has in its state a list of food items:

```
this.state = {
   items: [
      {
        name: 'Chicken',
        selectedServing: {
           label: 'breast, grilled',
           quantity: 3
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'French Fries',
        selectedServing: {
           label: 'medium container',
           quantity: 1
        }
      }
   ]
```

When a user changes the serving size they consumed, I have to update the properties of the item in the `items[]` array.  For example, if a user ate another chicken breast, I'd need to change the `selectedServing` object in `items[0]`.

Since this array is part of the component's state, I'm using immutability-helper.  I've found that I can properly clone and mutate the state in this way:

```
let newState = update(this.state, {
  items: {
    0: {
      selectedServing: {
        servingSize: {$set: newServingSize}
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The above code sets the servingSize for the first element in the `items[]` array, which is Chicken.  **However**, I won't know the index of the object I need to update beforehand, so the **0** I hardcoded won't work.  It seems that I can't store this index in a variable, because `update()` will think it's an object key.

How can I programmatically update an object at a specific index in a list?

Comment: you don't know the index that you want to update? Do you not have the it as a variable?

Comment: @riwu I do have it as a variable, but I'm unable to use it because the update method recognizes it as an object key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An variable can be used as a key of an object.

```
let foo = 3
let newState = { items: { [foo]: { somthing: 'newValue' } } }
// above is equal to { items: { '3': { somthing: 'newValue' } } }
```

You can find the index number of 'Chicken' and save it into an variable, and use it to composit newState.